# CakePHP 3.0 - Post Link - adding a class removes alert confirmation functionality

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How do can you add a class to this code?

```
$this->Form->postLink(
    __('Delete'),
    ['action' => 'delete', $user->id],
    ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]
)
```

When i add a class the "confirm functionality" disappears.

```
$this->Form->postLink(
    __('Delete'),
    ['action' => 'delete', $user->id],
    ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'],
    ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]
)
```

Comment: Show us the code where you added a class.

Comment: <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $user->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'],  ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]) ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set class before confirm

```
['class' => 'btn btn-danger','confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]
```

Comment: I get this error. 

Error: syntax error, unexpected '' => __('' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' 
File /Applications/AMPPS/www/tanv4_cake_theme/src/Template/Users/index.ctp 
Line: 59

Comment: is your class into the array with confirm?


the full link with your example, juste copy paste and that will do the job

echo $this->Form->postLink(
    __('Delete'),
    ['action' => 'delete', $user->id],
    ['class' => 'btn btn-danger','confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $_club_user->id)]
)

Comment: Look at the code highlighting @Gransfall You have a syntax error in your code example, you're missing a quote.

Answer (score 1):

`confirm` and `class` should be in same array

```
$this->Form->postLink(
    __('Delete'),
    ['action' => 'delete', $user->id],
    ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id),'class'=>'btn btn-danger']
)
```

Comment: Yep got it, Both should be in the same array. 

Thanks a lot :)